# jquery text() removes html tags and merges text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get text from a div with .text() using jQuery. This works, but the div is used as inline editor (tinymce), so there are some markups in there, for example:

```
<p>sometext<span id="_mce_caret" data-mce-bogus="true"><strong>sometext2</strong></span><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
```

The span is basically a new line, but when getting the text, all html tags are removed (which is needed), but the text is also merged together as one "word":

sometextsometext2

While it should be:

sometext sometext2

Maybe even as:

sometext. sometext2.

How to do this?

This is the code I already use:

```
var textareaValues = jQuery('.desc-meta').map(function(){
   return jQuery(this).text();
}).get();
console.log(textareaValues);
```

Thanks

**Edit**
Some more info on what was missing:
I have multiple divs (5 or 6):

```
<div class="desc-meta">
    <p>sometext<span id="_mce_caret" data-mce-bogus="true">
    <strong>sometext2</strong></span><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
</div>

<div class="desc-meta">
    <p>This is some extra sometext<span id="_mce_caret" data-mce-bogus="true">
    <strong>Some extra sometext2</strong></span><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
</div>

<div class="desc-meta">
    <p>sometext<span id="_mce_caret" data-mce-bogus="true">
    <strong>sometext2</strong></span><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
</div>
```

The text inside those divs need to be "merged" into 1 string, so the divs above should be:

```
sometext sometext2. This is some extra sometext Some extra sometext2. sometext sometext2.
```

This will be stored in a hidden input.
So without html tags, but keeping the spaces between words/sentences.

This is the jquery I have sofar:

```
var descText = '';
jQuery('#registration-form').find('.desc-meta').each(function(){

    if (jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).text()) != "") {
        var textareaValues = jQuery('.desc-meta').map(function(){
            return jQuery(this).text();
        }).get().join(' ');

        console.log(textareaValues);

        descText = textareaValues.join(', ');

    }

});
jQuery('#description').val(descText);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken your `.desc-meta` is the wrapper. So you should have given us the following HTML

```
<div class="desc-meta">
   <p>sometext<span id="_mce_caret" data-mce-bogus="true"><strong>sometext2</strong></span><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
</div>
```

Otherwise where is that class in your code?

So you are not looping from the elements within that wrapper div. Hence, you are just getting the contents of `desc-meta` as a string. In reality you want the contents of the elements within that class. So we use `find(*)` to get all the elements inside the wrapper div.

```
var textareaValues = jQuery('.desc-meta').find('*').map(function(){
   return jQuery(this).text();
}).get();
console.log(textareaValues);
```

Here, instead of looping through the container, we are looping through any element within the container, in your case, we are looping through the `p`, `span` and `strong`

The end result being this:

```
["sometextsometext2", "sometext2", "sometext2", ""]
```

Note, the first is the contents of the first `p`, which is everything within `p` the last empty value is the break. This is what you were trying to do and it doesn't work that good (especially if you don't know how many elements there are, if you do, then you just get `[1]` and `[2]` from above, and job's done.

---

A better way would be to get the html, and add the spaces yourself.

```
var textareaValues = jQuery('.desc-meta').map(function(){
   return jQuery(this).html();
}).get();
```

Above we get the html, now we need to add the spaces at the beginning of every element.

```
$str = textareaValues[0].split('<').join(' <');
```

**for multiple div containers us the following**

```
var str = textareaValues.join('').split('<').join(' <');
```

If you just want to `console.log($str)` the end result is ugly, but assuming you want to add it to the page.

```
$('body').append( $(str).text() )
```

The end result is with spaces.

Check out the [demo here](http://jsbin.com/milosif/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Still not working. What I forgot to tell, is that the .desc-meta are multiple divs, where I am getting the content from and I need to add it in a hidden field as plain text.

Comment: can you edit your code to reflect what you forgot to tell us?

Comment: for multiple divs use $str = textareaValues.join('').split('<').join(' <'); I edited the answer, I added a demo

Comment: Yeah I did and tried it, but your code has the $str append to the body, I need to add the text to a hidden input, if I add $str to that hidden input, the following is added to that value:
<p> <br data-mce-bogus="1"> </p> <p> <br data-mce-bogus="1"> </p> <p> <br data-mce-bogus="1"> </p> <p>sdaddsf <span data-mce-bogus="true" id="_mce_caret"> <strong>dsfgdfgdsfg </strong> </span> <br data-mce-bogus="1"> </p> <p>sdfgsgergerwg <br data-mce-bogus="1"> </p>

Comment: Ok, try my edits. use `var str`. Then append `$(str).text()` where ever you need. It removes the html tags and gives you the raw text.

Answer (score 0):

Id you would like to have a space between the words, just concat your space:

```
var textareaValues = jQuery('.desc-meta').map(function(){
   return jQuery(this).text();
}).get().join(" ");
console.log(textareaValues);
```

Comment: I know this, but I don't want the html tags, they should be removed.

Comment: I see if you like a space for each word, you could concat your space like this: `return jQuery(this).text() + " ";`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried that but still didn't work, still the "2 lines" are merged into 1 word.

Comment: Hmmm, still seems to be not working. What I forgot to tell, is that the .desc-meta are multiple divs, where I am getting the content from and I need to add it in a hidden field as plain text.